# Unable to set printer as default (Error 0x00000706)

Tags: windows, printer, network-printer

I am having an issue where a particular user is unable to set their default printer correctly after a reboot. The machine is running Windows 10 Pro with the latest updates installed.

This computer connects to two shared printers on another machine. Connecting to the printers and installing them works fine, and the user is able to set the desired printer as default without issue. However, once the machine is rebooted and they log back in, the other printer has now become the default and they cannot set the other one back.

The error message provided is 0x00000709. Searching around I've found several possible solutions that I've tried; such as giving full control to everyone on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows, deleting IsMRUEstablished and LegacyDefaultPrinterMode under HKEY_CURRENT_USER and running an SFC and DISM scan. There are no group policies or startup scripts that would be causing this either.

The printer in question is a Brother HL-L2370DW if that helps at all. All the other references to this issue I've been able to find is with HP printers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make sure the "Let Windows Manage my default printer" option is turned off. This setting is located in the Printers & Scanners setting window (Settings | Devices | Printers & scanners). You can find more information about this setting along with a registry setting [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/default-printer-keeps-changing-windows).

Comment: Thanks, I've made sure that setting is unchecked and the problem still persists though.